# .net core 1.1 entityframework and mysql database connection

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am install vs 2017 and try to create a test web api project with .net core 1.1 ,entity framework and my sql database .

bellow is package list I am using

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.0.0-preview1-final" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.7-m61" />
    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="1.1.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

and dbcontext class is

```
public class NorthWindDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public NorthWindDBContext()
        //: base(options)
        { }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                       .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

            var configuration = builder.Build();

            string connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("northwindConnection");
            optionsBuilder.UseMySql(connectionString);
        }


        public virtual DbSet<Customers> Customers { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Categories> Categories { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Products> Products { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Orders> Orders { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Order_Details> Order_Details { get; set; }



    }
```

but when I try to run an exception occurred

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type 'Categories'
>   requires a primary key to be defined.'

I don't understand whats going wrong.

please help

**UPDATE 1**
Bellow is the Categories Model

```
public class Categories
    {
        [Key]
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public byte Picture { get; set; }  

    }
```

I already have the database created in MySql.

**UPDATE 2**

```
 public class Categories
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]        
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public byte Picture { get; set; }


    }
```

**UPDATE 3**

```
public class Categories
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        [Key]
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public byte Picture { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Where are models for tables.  In Categories table model, there should be one [Key] before a key property.

Comment: Can you please share Categories table model?

Comment: Please see Update ,Categories model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The entity type 'Categories' **requires a primary key** to be defined.

Entity Framework requires a primary key to work. There are two ways to do this (that I know of).

- [Data Annotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591583(v=vs.113).aspx)
- [Fluent API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591617(v=vs.113).aspx)

For example

```
//Data Annotations
public class EmployeeEntity : BaseEntity
{
    // Denotes the primary key column
    [Key]
    // Add this if your column is not auto-generated
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public short Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    // more fields, probably
}

// Fluent API
public partial class EmployeeMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<EmployeeEntity>
{
    public EmployeeMap()
    {
        ToTable("employee");
        HasKey(emp => emp.Id)
          .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
    }
}
```

Note that if your Primary Key is not auto-generated, you need to tell EF using whichever method you chose.

Annotation: `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]`
Fluent: `HasKey(emp => emp.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);`

Comment: Please see Update ,Categories model.

Comment: @matrixwebtech Ah okay. See my edit about auto-generated keys. I recently ran into this problem, and it was happening due the fact that the MySQL connector assumes the PK column was auto-generated. I had to specify that it was not.

Comment: I change the model as per your suggestion ,see UPDATE 2 but not working .same exception.

Comment: @matrixwebtech You still need the `[Key]` annotation. Add both and try it again. I'll edit my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: @matrixwebtech What is the column name in the database? Is it an *exact* match? If not, you need to add the '[Column(name:"ActualColumnName")]' annotation. I will add here that I'm using the Fluent API method and it's working for me with MySQL 5.1. You might want to try that if you can't get annotations to work.

Comment: @matrixwebtech Good, I'm glad! Was it the column name issue, or did you end up using the Fluent API?